# JavaScript Increment counter with no fresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

i want to use this counter in smartry (.tpl) file. i have found script link is below

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fKve9/)

i just want to know where should i need to put these script code's

```
var START_DATE = new Date("October 10, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 30; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 35001; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;

 window.setInterval( function(){
    count += INCREMENT; 
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
 }, msInterval);

});
```

i mean where to put these in under  or  ? i want to use them in under  in smarty (.tpl) file. guide me because i am new in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code inside your Smarty template or in JS file depending on your needs.

Of course you need to load also jQuery.

Below there is a full Smarty `.tpl` file that uses your code and is working without a problem:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo counter</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div id="counter">


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}
    var START_DATE = new Date("October 10, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
    var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
    var INCREMENT = 30; // increase per tick
    var START_VALUE = 35001; // initial value when it's the start date
    var count = 0;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
        var now = new Date();
        count = parseInt((now - START_DATE) / msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;

        window.setInterval(function () {
            count += INCREMENT;
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
        }, msInterval);

    });
    {/literal}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```